# Doubt when translating しかも and しかと in this excerpt

Tags: translation, homophonic-kanji

I was reading an answer on [Yahoo! Chiebukuro](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1195558141) about *Nichijou* series. In the answer, the poster quoted an excerpt from a light novel *Nichijou no Shousetsu*. It's about a tale of *[Momotaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momotar%C5%8D)* being played by *Nichijou* characters.

> さて、さるをお供にしたももたろうが、元気良く鬼が島に歩いて行くと、その途中で、今度は犬が現れました。
>   「……!」
>   「……!」
>   **しかも、戦っています。**
>   **しかと、戦っています。**
>   いぬ役の校長先生が、役をほっぽり出して、**しかと戦っています**。校長先生、出番ですよー!
>   [中略]
>   **「な、なんでしかと戦っているのー!?」**
>   このおじさんが校長先生だと知らないももたろうは、あわてるばかり。
>   たしかに、街中で**いぬとしか**<sup>**(1)**</sup>**が戦っていたら**、誰だってびっくりします。

I could understand the overall meaning, but having a doubt on bolded sentence. When I was reading it the first time, I translated the bolded sentence as:

> 然も【しかも】、戦っています。
>   Moreover, he is fighting.
>
> 確と【しかと】、戦っています。
>   Certainly, he is fighting.

However, when I reached (1), I realized that I might be mistranslating しか since
 鹿【しか】 (deer) was more likely.

In the end, I translated them as

> 然も、戦っています。
>   Moreover, he is fighting.
>
> 鹿と、戦っています。
>   He is fighting with a deer.

One thing that made me doubtful was, as far as I know, there was no deer in *Momotarou*. However, I heard that there are alternative versions with different companies, so it might be just another variation that *Nichijou* created.

Also, I didn't translate しかも as 鹿も because it's the first time the deer was introduced, and there was no fighting introduced beforehand (in this excerpt).

Am I correct in translating those sentences? (I realized that the redacted excerpt might remove some important context, but it's beyond my control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your translation is good.

I think this was played on a street where there were deers because the content says that いぬ役の校長先生が、役をほっぽり出して、しかと戦っています(The school headmaster is fighting with a deer, forgetting his part as a dog) and 街中で(on a street). This 鹿 would not be related to the content of Momotaro.

Comment: I suspect the author was being deliberately ambiguous and wrote しか in hiragana to try to keep the reader wondering as long as possible.